# Secure Offline payment in Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment, offline, payment-processing

How can I implement offline payments using android mobiles?
When I said offline, It means the case can be both that **the user has network connection but don't have internet connection** and **the user don't have network( and don't have internet also) at all**. 
I am using sqlite to store content when offline and sync it with server, when the network is available.
My question is about secure method of transferring data between two devices, when they are offline(cellular network not available). Some things I thought of are:

1. SMS(if network is available)
2. NFC

   Note: The app uses it's own wallet which already has credits(money) transferred to it from bank, when it is online.

Edit: Both devices used here are android mobiles. Consider a scenario where : "A" transferred money to "B" in offline mode(Both A and B are offline) using **NFC**. After that A died(cannot be online forever), but B connected to internet. Now B tells server that A transferred some money to him. But the server **do not have any confirmation from A saying that B is telling truth**.

Question 1: How can I tackle this scenario?

Question 2: Is there any way better than NFC for  "A" to transfer money to "B" in offline mode?

Comment: "My question is about secure method of transferring data between two devices, when they are offline(cellular network not available)" - I'm not clear what you're asking. One of these devices is the Android mobile of the user who wants to pay, what is the other device? What role does it play in taking payment?

Comment: Both devices are android mobiles. Consider this scenario: "A" transferred money to "B" in offline mode(Both A and B are offline) using NFC. After that A died(cannot be online forever), but B connected to internet. Now B tells server that A transferred some money to him. But the server do not have any confirmation from A saying that B is telling truth.
Question 1: How can I tackle this scenario?
Question 2: Is there any way better than NFC for  "A" to transfer money to "B" in offline mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use  SQLite to store data onto the mobile database when offline and later when online update the SQL database server. Use [this link to understand sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: I think this should be used with care because most payment systems work with session which have a very short lifetime. So storing something in the database without any indication on how long it will be there, and hope for the server to accept what is sent back seems a pretty bad idea to me

Comment: Yeah.. As @ArthurAttout said, we don't know how long the user will be offline. And we also need a fallback when one of the users cannot connect to internet forever.

Comment: Actually Prabhu is thinking of a wallet kind of system, where he has given his users facilities of depositing money like in most of the wallets and later users can use that credits for their purposes within the application. So, it wont be an issue in case of wallets, as transaction is done before while adding credits into the wallet, later @prabhu only needs to save the credits used into sqlite and minus it with the credits in the online database.

Comment: Edited question for more clarity.
Also what if one of the users cannot connect to internet forever.